# Android get layout name where string is used

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Is there any way to get layout where string is used.
Example: "submit" string is used in registration layout. How can I know it?

Comment: can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 private HashSet<TextView> getTextViews(ViewGroup root){
    HashSet<TextView> views=new HashSet<>();
    for(int i=0;i<root.getChildCount();i++){
        View v=root.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof TextView){
            if (((TextView) v).getText().equals("YOUR_STRING")){
                views.add((TextView)v);
            }
        }
    }
    return views;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've only asked half a question so I'm making some assumptions

- That you are talking about in your code and IDE - NOT runtime
- That you correctly store your strings in Strings.xml
- That you are using Android Studio (and windows)

Open Strings.xml, Click the Key (Name) part of your resource and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to Find Usages.

Alternatively if you need to do a full text search press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to search your whole project with Find in Path

**Edit to address comment**

To find the view with "Submit" text using Espresso you can use either of these lines

```
onView(withText("Submit"));
onView(withText(R.string.submit));
```

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention, I need to get it via programming to so can open that via in some espresso tests.

Comment: So your question is about how to find a view with espresso!? That's not remotely related to what you've written, but I know the solution also